# Error while passing integer data as parameter from textbox at run time while inserting into ms access database using c++ mfc

Tags: visual-c++

My code is as follows

```
int x=0;
CString Number;
TRY
{
// Open the database
database.Open(NULL,false,false,sDsn);
CSampleDlg sample=new CSampleDlg();

// Allocate the recordset
CRecordset recset( &database );

// insert data
recset.m_pDatabase->BeginTrans();
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1)->GetWindowText(Number);
x=_wtoi(Number);
      recset.m_pDatabase->ExecuteSQL(L"INSERT INTO  Categories (Category) VALUES(+=@x)");
```

I get error in above line while inserting integer data at runtime from text box

Comment: What is "L" .. L"INSERT ... and what kind of err msg ?

Comment: @matzone - the "L" is a quoted `wchar_t`.